# Defining loss weights with a target tensor

Tags: keras, tensorflow

We have a model with an output target that is a 2D tensor.  That is, the output represents a set of n classes, evaluated at m bins within the data.  That is the output shape is: `[none, n, m]`.  Furthermore, the classes are highly imbalanced, so we need to use weights to balance the losses across the classes.

For example, the target shape with three classes (A, B, and C), four bins and a batch size of 1 would be:

```
Target = 
 [[[A1, A2, A3, A4],
   [B1, B2, B3, B4],
   [C1, C2, C3, C4]]]
```

I've researched the use of Class-weights with Keras and it is extensively discussed, but 99% of the time the output is a class vector with a single target result for each class.  In our case, we have a target **array** for each class.

I would hypothesize that we could use a possible weight tensor such as this:

```
Weights = 
  [[Wa, Wa, Wa, Wa],
   [Wb, Wb, Wb, Wb],
   [Wc, Wc, Wc, Wc]]
```

Where a constant weight value is applied to each class for each of its bins.
But I'm unsure if the shape should be `[n, m]` or `[none, n, m]` or `[b, n, m]` (where b is the batch size).  I'm also unsure if this is considered a `loss_weight` or a `class_weight`.

I've looked at using `loss_weights`, `class_weights` and `weight_metrics` but the documentation is thin for non-vector outputs.

My question: how does one apply weights to a output tensor?

EDIT 1:
I'm starting to think that the `samples_weights` option may be the best approach here.
Here is a [discussion](https://twitter.com/fchollet/status/1471067209569087499?lang=en) by Francois Chollett offering his thoughts.

Comment: Not sure I fully understand your setting, but the clearest way would be to just write your own loss function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the recommendation from @Adam we went ahead and built a custom loss function to accept sample-weights.  Because we are using a dataset (`tf.data`) pipeline, we append the sample-weights tensor to the training dataset only, resulting in a three-tuple of: (InputTensor, TargetTensor, WeightTensor). For the test/val dataset, we do not append the weights, resulting in a two-tuple of: (InputTensor, TargetTensor).
The sample-weights tensor is constructed as listed above in the question:

```
Weights = 
  [[Wa, Wa, Wa, Wa],
   [Wb, Wb, Wb, Wb],
   [Wc, Wc, Wc, Wc]]
```

The loss function is:

```
class WeightedCategoricalCrossentropySimple(tf.keras.losses.Loss):
    def __init__(self, y_true, y_pred, **kwargs):   # Note: these variables are NOT used, but there is a bug in TF that calls the constructor incorrectly with these values; we need to consume them but dont need to use them
        super().__init__()

    def call(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight = None):
        # Compute cross-entropy loss for each sample in batch
        loss_per_sample = tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)

        # Apply weighting to each sample in batch, but only if present
        if sample_weight:
            loss_per_sample = tf.multiply(loss_per_sample, sample_weight)

        loss = tf.reduce_mean(loss_per_sample)

        return loss
```

The dataset pipeline creation code adds one line to apply the weights to the pipelines (if present) just before batching the tensors:

```
def load_tfrecord_dataset(...
                          weights = None             # type: np.array
                          ):
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(file_pattern)
    dataset = dataset.interleave(
        lambda tfr: tf.data.TFRecordDataset(tfr, compression_type="GZIP"),
            num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

    dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=buffer_size).repeat(1)
    dataset = dataset.map(_parse_tfrecord_single_class, num_parallel_calls=5)

    # Appends the weight matrix as a third parameter, but only if present
    dataset = dataset.map(lambda x, y: append_weights(x, y, weights))

    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size=batch_size, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE, drop_remainder=True)
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
    return dataset
```

Where `append_weights()` is defined as:

```
def append_weights(x, y, weights):
    if weights is not None:
        return x, y, weights
    else:
        return x, y
```